# amcharts group by days and minutes

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am in the situation where people can choose between many different time intervals like

- 1d (5minute data)
- 1year (1day data)

If I put this in `"groupToPeriods": ["DD"]` it will display the days perfectly when it is etc 1-year data.

If I put this in `"groupToPeriods": ["NN"]` it will display the minutes perfectly when it is etc 1-day data.

Days
[image]

Minutes
[image]

How do I make it work both with NN and DD at the same time? should I automatically put in either NN or DD depending on which type of data I provide? This is not the case in one of the other sample charts I've tried there it did it automatically, however, that was not one of the stock charts, but normal charts.

I tried this `"groupToPeriods": ["DD-NN"]` and `"groupToPeriods": ["DD", "NN"]` without any luck, [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/understanding-data-grouping-of-stock-chart/) and [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/) is some documentation ive read about grouping and date formatting.

```
var redaw = false;
var logarithmic = false;
var interval = "all";

function createChart1(chartData) {
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivs", {
    "type": "stock",
    "theme": "light",
    "recalculateToPercents": "never",
    "dataSets": [{
      "title": "$",
      "fieldMappings": [{
        "fromField": "value",
        "toField": "value"
      }, {
        "fromField": "volume",
        "toField": "volume"
      }],
      "dataProvider": chartData,
      "categoryField": "date",
      "color": "#2e4259",
      "fillAlphas": 0.5
    }],
    "panels": [{
      "title": "Fiat",
      "showCategoryAxis": false,
      "percentHeight": 70,
      "color": "#fff",
      "recalculateToPercents": "never",
      "stockGraphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "valueField": "value",
        "comparable": true,
        "lineThickness": "3px",
        "compareField": "value",
        "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
        "compareGraphBalloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
        "color": "#fff"
      }]
    }, {
      "title": "Volume",
      "percentHeight": 30,
      "color": "#fff",
      "stockGraphs": [{
        "valueField": "volume",
        "type": "line",
        "showBalloon": false,
        "fillAlphas": 0.5
      }],
      "stockLegend": {
        "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]",
        "marginRight": 10,
        "color": "#fff"
      }
    }],

    "panelsSettings": {
      //    "color": "#fff",
      "plotAreaBorderAlpha": 0.5,
      "plotAreaBorderColor": "#2e4259",
      "marginLeft": 30,
      "marginRight": 30,
      "marginTop": 5,
      "marginBottom": 30
    },

    "categoryAxesSettings": {
      "equalSpacing": true,
      "gridColor": "#2e4259",
      "gridAlpha": 0.5,
      "maxSeries": 1,
      //////////////////////////////////// HERE IS THE PROBLEM ////////////////////////////////////
      "groupToPeriods": ["DD-NN"]
    },

    "valueAxesSettings": {
      "logarithmic": logarithmic,
      "gridColor": "#2e4259",
      "gridAlpha": 0.5,
      "inside": false,
      "showLastLabel": false
    },
    "chartScrollbarSettings": {
      "graph": "g1",
      //            "graphFillColor": "#000",
      "backgroundColor": "transparent",
      "gridAlpha": 0,
      "graphFillAlpha": 0.8,
      "graphLineAlpha": 0,
      "graphLineColor": "#fff",
      "graphType": "line",
      "updateOnReleaseOnly": false,
      "graphFillColor": "#2e4259",
      "selectedBackgroundColor": "#2e4259",
      "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
      "selectedGraphFillColor": "#2e4259"
    },
    "chartCursorSettings": {
      "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
      "fullWidth": false,
      "cursorAlpha": 0.5,
      "valueLineBalloonEnabled": false,
      "valueLineEnabled": false,
      "cursorColor": "#000"
    }
  });

  redaw === true ? chart.validateData() : redaw = true;
}

function generateChartData() {
  var chartData1 = [];
  // current date
  var firstDate = new Date();
  // now set 500 minutes back
  firstDate.setMinutes(firstDate.getDate() - 1000);


  var CSRFToken = document.getElementById("CSRFToken").value;
  var parameters = "CSRFToken=" + CSRFToken + "&interval=" + interval + "&id=" + 1;
  console.log("INTERVAL: " + interval);
  ajax("/pages/ajax/request-chart-data.php", parameters, "POST", false, function(results) {
    if (results) {
      var jsonObj = JSON.parse(results);
      console.log("JSON OBJ");
      console.log(jsonObj);
      for (var i in jsonObj) {

        var newDate = new Date(jsonObj[i].date);
        chartData1.push({
          "date": newDate,
          "value": jsonObj[i].price,
          "volume": jsonObj[i].volume
        });
      }
      createChart1(chartData1);
    } else {
      console.log("NO RESULTS");
    }
  });
}
generateChartData();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. [`groupToPeriods`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#groupToPeriods) groups data based on whatever your [`maxSeries`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#maxSeries) is set to in period ascending order; using the default value as an example, - first it starts with seconds (`ss`), then 10 seconds (`10ss`), 30 seconds (`30ss`), then minutes (`mm`), 10 minutes (`10mm`), 30 minutes (`30mm`) then days (`DD`), weeks (`WW`), months (`MM`) then years (`YYYY`). You can't combine multiple periods in one grouping, so in your case, with your extremely small `maxSeries` setting, set it to the smallest period you want to group to based on your data. Also note that there is no `NN` period - it's `mm` for minutes. You also need to set an appropriate [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#groupToPeriods) as well, which also takes a single period type, to ensure that your data is rendered correctly as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will look further into minPeriod, for now, it seems to screw up my 5minute data intervals, i did however change the DD/mm dynamically depending on which data type i provide